# php dynamic variable to side by side array insert to database problem

Tags: php, wordpress

i hope i can explain my problem :)

```
$count = 0;
while( have_rows('wordpress_acf_plugin_variable',$id) ) : the_row();
    $count++;
                                    
    $cevapsecenek .='<b>Question '.$count.'</b>: 
        <input type="radio" name="question_'.$count.'" value="A"> A 
        <input type="radio" name="question_'.$count.'" value="B"> B 
        <input type="radio" name="question_'.$count.'" value="C"> C 
        <input type="radio" name="question_'.$count.'" value="D"> D
        <br>';
endwhile;
```

frontend screen for this code;

```
Question 1: () A () B () C () D
Question 2: () A () B () C () D
. . .
```

and when member(student) send submit button.

```
$scount = 0;
$studenquestionanswers = array();
while( have_rows('wordpress_acf_plugin_variable',$id) ) : the_row();
    $scount++;
    ${'question_'.$scount} = $_POST['question_'.$scount];
    $answers = get_sub_field('answersfrom_acf_plugin_variable');
                    
    if(${'question_'.$scount}==$answers) {
        $trueanswers += 1;
    } else {
        $wronganswers += 1;
    }
    $emptyanswers = $scount - ($trueanswers + $wronganswers);
    $studenquestionanswers[] = $_POST['question_'.$scount];
endwhile;
```

my problem only this code

```
$studenquestionanswers[] = $_POST['question__'.$scount];`
```

i want insert student's answers to database like "ABCD"

Comment: Do you mean you want a string containing `"ABCD"` if so try `$studenquestionanswers .= $_POST['question_'.$scount];` and change the initialisation to `$studenquestionanswers = ''`

Comment: Also I don't know if it's just a typo here on Stackoverflow, but this line is incorrect: `$studenquestionanswers[] = $_POST['question__'.$scount];` -- note the extra underscore after 'question'

Comment: i only wrong write to here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u want to combine all answers in one string you can join them. After while loop write:

```
$studenquestionanswers = join('', $studenquestionanswers);
```